# Altering the Characters of a Dataframe in R

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a *column* in an R Dataframe that has values of the form `21`, `2021`, `18`, `2019`, and so on. Basically, the value 21 is the same as the value 2021 because the column contains values for years. I am trying to write code in R which replaces all the instances of years that have a length of 2 and replaces them with a "20" appended in the beginning. For example, "18" should turn into "2018". Can someone suggest what code should be used to achieve this? I am thinking of using the `ifelse` command but I am not sure what the exact syntax should be.

Comment: Assuming the year column is numeric: `transform(DF, year = year + 2000 * (year < 100))`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Works like a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Count the number of characters and add `'20'` to them which are less than equal to 2.

```
df <- data.frame(year = c(21, 2021, 18, 2019))
transform(df,year = as.integer(paste0(ifelse(nchar(year) <= 2, '20', ''), year)))

#  year
#1 2021
#2 2021
#3 2018
#4 2019
```